# Проблема с кодировкой при парсинге сайта

Tags: кодировка, php, синтаксический-анализ

при парсинге некоторых сайтов имеются проблемы с кодировкой (например Wikipedia).
После загрузки страницы cUrl-ом выводит нормально, но если разобрать и собрать DOMDocument -ом то получается что то вроде такого "Р’РёРєРёРїРµРґРёСЏ"

```
$ch = curl_init('http://ru.wikipedia.org/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1');
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html);
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Все скрипты в UTF-8